# Russian version of "The apple didn't fall far from the tree"

Tags: идиомы

This idiom means that children usually end up being similar to their parents. Are there any Russian versions of this that are not direct translations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The direct translation (яблоко от яблони недалеко падает) is very well-known, but there's also a humorous version that's less popular:

> Яйца от курицы недалеко падают.
> (The eggs don't fall far from the hen.)

Comment: Never heard the one about eggs. Probably self-made... Though it is humorous indeed, as everything involving eggs...

Answer (score 5):

There is a rhyming phrase *"От осинки не родятся апельсинки"* (оranges will not be born from aspen).
The phrase is quite well-known, but in terms of frequency of use it is inferior to the mega-popular saying about the apple tree and apples.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the literal translation, there are many more variations on [Matthew 7:16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_7:16) in [Dahl](https://vdahl.ru/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F/), for example:

Отец рыбак, и дети в воду смотрят - the father is a fisherman and the children look towards the water, too

От худого семени не жди племени - from bad seed, expect no yield.